# Calculating AUPR in R

Tags: r, precision-recall

It is easy to find a package calculating area under ROC, but is there a package that calculates the area under precision-recall curve?

Comment: [ROCR](http://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/), [pROC](http://web.expasy.org/pROC/) - are really nice!

Comment: They certainly are, yet AFAIK neither can calculate the area under precision-recall curve.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As of July 2016, the package [PRROC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PRROC/vignettes/PRROC.pdf) works great for computing both ROC AUC and PR AUC.

Assuming you already have a vector of probabilities (called `probs`) computed with your model and the true class labels are in your data frame as `df$label` (0 and 1) this code should work:

```
install.packages("PRROC")

require(PRROC)
fg <- probs[df$label == 1]
bg <- probs[df$label == 0]

# ROC Curve    
roc <- roc.curve(scores.class0 = fg, scores.class1 = bg, curve = T)
plot(roc)

# PR Curve
pr <- pr.curve(scores.class0 = fg, scores.class1 = bg, curve = T)
plot(pr)
```

PS: The only disconcerting thing is you use `scores.class0 = fg` when `fg` is computed for label 1 and not 0.

Here are the example ROC and PR curves with the areas under them:

[image: ROC Curve with AUC]

[image: PR Curve with AUC]

The bars on the right are the threshold probabilities at which a point on the curve is obtained.

Note that for a random classifier, ROC AUC will be close to 0.5 irrespective of the class imbalance. However, the PR AUC is tricky (see [What is "baseline" in precision recall curve](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251175/what-is-baseline-in-precision-recall-curve)).

Comment: Pls refer to the PRROC documentation linked in the answer above.

Answer (score 4):

`AUPRC()` is a function in the `PerfMeas` package which is much better than the `pr.curve()` function in `PRROC` package when the data is very large.
`pr.curve()` is a nightmare and takes forever to finish when you have vectors with millions of entries. `PerfMeas` takes seconds in comparison. `PRROC` is written in R and `PerfMeas` is written in C.

Answer (score 2):

A little googling returns one bioc package, [qpgraph](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.4/bioc/html/qpgraph.html) (`qpPrecisionRecall`), and a cran one, [minet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/minet/) (`auc.pr`). I have no experience with them, though. Both have been devised to deal with biological networks.

Comment: This minet looked nice, but it needs to have some external adapter to make appropriate input from general data :-(

Answer (score 2):

Once you've got a precision recall curve from `qpPrecisionRecall`, e.g.:

```
pr <- qpPrecisionRecall(measurements, goldstandard)
```

you can calculate its AUC by doing this:

```
f <- approxfun(pr[, 1:2])
auc <- integrate(f, 0, 1)$value
```

the help page of `qpPrecisionRecall` gives you details on what data structure expects in its arguments.

Comment: Doesn't the PR-curve require some more fancy integration? See: http://mnd.ly/oWQQw1